# How to change NaN into Integer

Tags: jquery, numbers, number-formatting

I have view like this

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <label>Harga Normal</label>
    <input id="NormalPrice" type="text" size="30" class="form-control number uang" name="NormalPrice" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <label>Harga Diskon</label>
    <input id="DiscountPrice" type="text" size="30" class="form-control number" name="DiscountPrice" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <label>Hari aktif kupon</label>
    <input id="CouponActiveDay" type="text" min="0" max="365" class="form-control number" name="CouponActiveDay" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

and I want to make make the text to be number, so I am using like this

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"></script>
function count(){
  var res = (Number($('#NormalPrice').val()) - Number($('#DiscountPrice').val())) / Number($('#NormalPrice').val()) * 100;
  $('#Discount').val(parseInt(res)+"%");
}
$('#DiscountPrice').keyup(count);

$(document).on('keypress','.number',function(e){
  if((e.which <= 57 && e.which >= 48) || (e.keyCode >= 37 && e.keyCode <= 40) || e.keyCode==9 || e.which==43 || e.which==44 || e.which==45 || e.which==46 || e.keyCode==8){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
});

$(document).on('blur','.uang',function(){
  $(this).val(numeral($(this).val()).format('0,0'));
}).on('focus','.uang',function(){
  $(this).val($(this).val());
});
```

[image]
But when I input no more than 3 digits on NormalPrice.. I can get the Discount Value.. but if I input more than 3 digits, I get NaN and I think that it returns string, but I have used parseInt.

Comment: [`<input type="number"> - HTML | MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

Comment: @Pete I have used parseInt(). but It returns NaN

Comment: The problem: `$(this).val(numeral($(this).val()).format('0,0'));` (and why `$(this).val($(this).val());` o.O)

Comment: @Andreas Do you have the other way to get number format when blur?
I am using `$(this).val(Number($(this).val()));` If I am only using `Number($(this).val())`.. when I focus, my textfield will display NaN

Comment: If you enter `1000` it will become `1,000` on blur, and `Number('1,000')` is `NaN`. By do you want to add the `,` in the form anyway. It will result in many problems.

Comment: @t.niese what should I do? I think if I enter 1000 and it will become 1,000.. 1,000 is a string. Am I right??

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: No matter if you write `100` or `1,000` is in the form, it is always a string. But `1,000` is not a valid parseable number format in JavaScript, so it results in `NaN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you format the numeric value to have a thousand separator you're converting it to a string. One workaround would be to replace the comma inside your `count` function.

```
function count(){
    var res = (Number($('#NormalPrice').val().replace(/,/g,'')) - Number($('#DiscountPrice').val().replace(/,/g,''))) / Number($('#NormalPrice').val().replace(/,/g,'')) * 100;
    $('#Discount').val(parseInt(res)+"%");
}
```

**Edit: explanation**

`Number('1,000')` is NaN, whereas `Number('1000')` is 1000.
What you're doing here is replacing the comma before passing it to `Number`. Now, you don't want to alter the value displayed in the input, because then it would be meaningless to format it beforehand. So I apply `replace` over the value instead of altering the value itself.

When you [replace text on a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace) you're generating a new string with the replacement applied. You could do, for example

```
"1,000".replace(',','') // outputs "1000"
```

But it will only replace the first occurence of a comma. So you could face a problem if you do

```
"1,000,000".replace(',','') // outputs "1000,000"
```

When you use a regexp, you can tell it to replace very comma:

```
"1,000,000".replace(/,/g,'') // outputs "1000000"
```

The `g` parameter (which I had forgot to include before this edition) means exactly: "every occurence".

Comment: Woah, thankyou..
It works.. But, can you explain a little to me.. `what is replace(/,/,'')` and why I need to put that?

Comment: I added an explanation to my answer

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `parseInt` parses string and returns integer of base 10 or `NaN` if it cannot parse it. If it is not string it tries to convert it into string first. I believe it is because you use coma as number formatting.

My suggestion is to put breakpoint on line where you set `res` variable and inspect what actual value.

[Number.parseInt Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt)